# How to skip ahead one step and set a value if only one checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently creating a donation form that uses steps. To move from step to step, I am using jQuery (specifically the following function):

```
function showNextStep(currentStep) {
    $("#step" + currentStep).slideToggle("slow", function () {
        if (currentStep === 1) {
            //figure out what kind of donation they are making
            var chosenDonationType = $("[name=donationType]").val();
            //show the apppropriate slide
            switch (chosenDonationType) {
            case "oneTimeGift":
                currentStep += 1;
                $("#makingAOneTimeGift").show();
                $("#step" + currentStep).slideToggle("slow");
                break;
            case "recurringDonation":
                currentStep += 1;
                $("#makingARecurringGift").show();
                $("#step" + currentStep).slideToggle("slow");
                break;
                //if somehow they changed it to something else, ignore them and return false.
            default:
                return false;
                //break; not needed due to return
            }//end switch
        } else {
            currentStep += 1;
            $("#step" + currentStep).slideToggle("slow");
        }
    });
}
```

I have a list of funds that the user can donate to as well. The step after this (id="step4") is for allocations. I want to skip that step and set the corresponding input value to 100 if the user only selects one checkbox. Catch is, I don't know how to run through the array of checkboxes (I'm assuming using [name=list-item]) and find that only one is selected, identify which one, and then skip the step next step and set the value to of the respective allocation box to 100. What would be a performance effective way to do this?

Checkboxes use the following style:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="showGoodMenGoodCitizensAllocation" name="list-items[]" value="Good_Men_Good_Citizens" />
    Good Men, Good Citizens Scholarship
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="showClassof2012Allocation" name="list-items[]" value="Class_Of_2012" />
    Class of 2012 Scholarship <abbr title="In Honor Of">IHO</abbr> Mr. Jason M. Ferguson &rsquo;96
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="showClassof2011Allocation" name="list-items[]" value="Class_Of_2011" />
    Class of 2011 Scholarship <abbr title="In Honor Of">IHO</abbr> Ms. Anita Garland
</label>
```

The allocation inputs are as follows:

```
<div id="GoodMenGoodCitizensAllocation" class="input-append hiddenByDefault">
    <input type="number" name="Good_Men_Good_Citizens-Allocation" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
    <span class="add-on">&#37; to the Good Men, Good Citizens Scholarship</span>
</div>
<div id="ClassOf2012Allocation" class="input-append hiddenByDefault">
    <input type="number" name="Class_Of_2012-Allocation" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
    <span class="add-on">&#37; to the Class of 2012 Scholarship <abbr title="In Honor Of">IHO</abbr> Mr. Jason M. Ferguson &rsquo;96</span>
</div>
<div id="ClassOf2011Allocation" class="input-append hiddenByDefault">
    <input type="number" name="Class_Of_2011-Allocation" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
    <span class="add-on">&#37; to the Class of 2011 Scholarship <abbr title="In Honor Of">IHO</abbr> Ms. Anita Garland</span>
</div>
```

For the full page code:
http://pastebin.com/yFv2day1

For the full javascript code currently used:
http://pastebin.com/P0YVRuqY

Resources I am using:

- PHP
- jQuery 1.8.3
- Twitter Bootstrap

Thank you all in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
var $chck = $("#step3 :checkbox:checked");
if ($chck.length === 1) {
  var selectedVal = $chck.val();//do whatever you want with that
  currentStep += 2;
} else 
  currentStep++;  

$("#step" + currentStep).slideToggle("slow");
```

Comment: So I could add that to the showNextStep function like below? How would I identify which checkbox was selected though?

    `if ($("#step3 :checkbox:checked").length === 1) {
            //identify which checkbox and set the allocation
            currentStep += 2;
                $("#step" + currentStep).slideToggle("slow");
            } else {
                currentStep += 1;
                $("#step" + currentStep).slideToggle("slow");
            }
}`

Comment: That worked. Now I just have to figure out why it broke my showPreviousStep function. Probably something I did

Comment: do you know if there is a way for the currentStep variable being set in the function to change the variable that was passed into the function? I.E. when doing `currentStep += 2` it's not changing the `currentStep` outside of the function breaking the ability to go back a step correctly.

Comment: You have to return value from your called function

Comment: sorry for the continuous questions, so I would run the step as `currentStep = showNextStep(currentStep)`? I added `return currentStep` to the bottom of the `showNextStep` function and it doesn't update the variable when running it as `currentStep = showNextStep(currentStep)`. See [http://kirsches.us/Online_Gift_Form](http://kirsches.us/Online_Gift_Form) for an example

Comment: You should open a new question and post it all relevant code as your new showNextStep() function code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14239968/javascript-multistep-form-wont-update-variable-value-outside-of-function-when-r

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over an array of checkboxes and find out which is checked:

```
$("#YOUR-FORM input[type=checkbox]").each(function (i, e) {

    if ($(e).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        // This checkbox is checked... do some stuff
    } else {
        // Not checked...ignore
    }

});
```

For skipping the step I'll need to take a longer look but that should get you started...

Comment: Or just use `$("#YOUR-FORM input[type=checkbox]:checked")` to get all checked inputs.

Comment: Sorry for the simple follow up, what is the `i` and `e` variable standing for? I can assume the `e` would be each item, but I'm not sure. Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: `i` is the number in list of the item, 0-indexd, `e` is the element itself, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

@zch true, but in this case I thought a loop would be easier for him to understand and he might want to run some code per checkbox. You way works just as well though and is most likely more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example I made to run when a button is clicked:

```
$(function () {
  $('#evaluate').click(function () {
    var checked = $('input[name="list-items[]"]:checked');
    if (checked.length == 1) {
      alert('one checked: ' + checked.val());
    } else {
      var vals = [];
      checked.each(function () {
        vals.push($(this).val());
      });
      alert(checked.length + " boxes checked: " + vals);
      }
    })
  });
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tVt2A/)